# Correct files found by “Bad Files Check” in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox account that has numerous files reported as "bad" via:

https://www.dropbox.com/bad_files_check

As there are a couple of hundred files that are invalid is there any automated way to fix them aside from using the web interface to do them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no in built feature which dropbox provides a mass delete function for all your bad files, best case would be do obtain all the files on your drive and use an external program from there

Comment: I don't want to delete them, I want to rename them. And getting them to my computer is the issue as they are not compliant with the OS I am using and the amount of data in there is many GB

Comment: well, I looked through the unofficial drop box add-ons listed here, http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons but there isn't an fix for your issue, its just an problem of being limited to the service you are using, so you may have to manually go through the files to rename them.

Comment: Ended up doing them all by hand *sigh*

Comment: I gave you some rep, that should give you some motivation

Answer (score 2):

I have created a small app that can correct all the files that are marked "bad" in Dropbox. You can download it here: https://github.com/davidcruy/bad-files-check

This app connects to the Dropbox API with your credentials and renames the files so that your Dropbox can sync them again.

To run the app you need a token, you can get your token here:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/

With the token run the following command:
`dropbox-bfc.exe -o output.csv -f bearer`

That command will scan all your folders and fix the files + folders if it encounters a name that is not OS friendly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).